# Eigen: vector of linear system solver

Tags: c++, vector, eigen, eigen3

I'm working with the Eigen linear algebra library and need a vector of `BiCGSTAB`-solvers. Unfortunately, extending this vector is extremely difficult. The minimal (not) working example is

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

int main() {
    std::vector< Eigen::BiCGSTAB< Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > > > tmp;
    tmp.emplace_back();
}
```

and yields the error message

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/vector:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/functional:62,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:85,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool std::__check_constructible() [with _ValueType = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&&]’:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:182:4:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*>; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:372:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*>; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*; _Allocator = allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:487:3:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; iterator = std::vector<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >::iterator]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:123:21:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; reference = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&]’
main.cpp:5:21:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
   90 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType, _Tp>::value,
      |                                                        ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: note: ‘std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value’ evaluates to false
```

Trying to `std::move` is worse, i.e.

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::vector< Eigen::BiCGSTAB< Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > > > tmp;

    Eigen::BiCGSTAB< Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > > solver;
    tmp.push_back( std::move( solver ) );
}
```

leads to the error message

```
g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:50,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Args = {Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<double> >}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:516:17:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_CharT> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Args = {Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<double> >}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; allocator_type = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:117:30:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<double> >}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; reference = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1294:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(value_type&&) [with _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; value_type = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >]’
main.cpp:9:18:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:175:11: error: use of deleted function ‘Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >::BiCGSTAB(const Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&)’
  175 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:42,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:31,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/BiCGSTAB.h:158:7: note: ‘Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >::BiCGSTAB(const Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  158 | class BiCGSTAB : public IterativeSolverBase<BiCGSTAB<_MatrixType,_Preconditioner> >
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/BiCGSTAB.h:158:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >::IterativeSolverBase(const Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:38:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/IterativeSolverBase.h:143:7: note: ‘Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >::IterativeSolverBase(const Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  143 | class IterativeSolverBase : public SparseSolverBase<Derived>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/IterativeLinearSolvers/IterativeSolverBase.h:143:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >::SparseSolverBase(const Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/SparseCore:64,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:26:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSolverBase.h:67:7: note: ‘Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >::SparseSolverBase(const Eigen::SparseSolverBase<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   67 | class SparseSolverBase : internal::noncopyable
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSolverBase.h:67:7: error: ‘Eigen::internal::noncopyable::noncopyable(const Eigen::internal::noncopyable&)’ is private within this context
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:162:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:424:21: note: declared private here
  424 |   EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC noncopyable(const noncopyable&);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/vector:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/functional:62,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:85:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr bool std::__check_constructible() [with _ValueType = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&&]’:
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:182:4:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*>; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:372:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*>; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*; _ForwardIterator = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >*; _Allocator = allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:487:3:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<double> >}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; iterator = std::vector<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >::iterator]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/vector.tcc:123:21:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, 0, int>, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<double> >}; _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; reference = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >&]’
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1294:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(value_type&&) [with _Tp = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > >; value_type = Eigen::BiCGSTAB<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >]’
main.cpp:9:18:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
   90 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType, _Tp>::value,
      |                                                        ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:90:56: note: ‘std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value’ evaluates to false
```

I'm using Eigen 3.4 and `g++` version 12.2.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like the base class suppresses copying/moving of these objects which the vector needs if it wants to resize itself. If you switch from vector to ```std::deque```, then ```emplace_back()``` works.

Comment: Thanks @Homer512, I didn't know that `std::dequeue` allows random access. Then this will do.

Comment: And if you know a-priori how many solvers you need, ```std::unique_ptr<Eigen::BICGSTAB<...>[]>``` also works. Plain old ```new Array[n]``` syntax. Make sure not to forget the ```[]``` in the pointer template to get the array specialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into a proper answer:

After looking at the code, I found that `BiCGSTAB` like all solvers inherits from a base class designed to prevent copying, and by extension moving, too: `class SparseSolverBase : internal::noncopyable`

The exact reasons for this design choice I cannot tell. If I had to guess, I'd say some solvers probably use self-referential attributes (holding pointers to other members) which would break especially with fixed-size matrices. Or using `Eigen::Map` may cause issues on copy, especially copy-assignment.

`std::vector` only works with moveable types as it needs to move when it reallocates. Even when calling `reserve()` beforehand, the code still needs to compile, even if it is never executed.

Three workarounds come to mind:

1. Use `std::deque`. It provides a superset of all methods that vector has but its implementation means that as long as you only call `emplace_back` or `emplace_front` and not e.g. `insert`, it does not need moveable types. The downside is that it is a bit slower on all individual accesses
2. Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Solver>>`. Less efficient than the deque but now you can also insert, reshuffle, etc.
3. Use `std::unique_ptr<Solver[]>` and use the good old `new Solver[count]` allocation. Starting with C++14, you can use `std::make_unique<Solver[]>(count)`. This has the least overhead, even less than vector but the interface isn't as nice (you can use the `[index]` operator but the pointer doesn't even know the array size) and the number is fixed after allocation